# Condition Custom Action in project setup

Tags: c#, windows-installer, setup-project

I have a project installer (msi setup) which have 2 radio button for the user to select from, 
I have also custom Actions which installing services according to user choice,

when I'm trying in the condition the condition I want it always return false and skipping install all the services no matter what the user chosen.

can anyone put me in the right direction what I'm doing wrong? 
is this kind of behaviour is even possible?
[image]

Comment: See installation log and check whether your custom action is running at all and what's happening with the condition.

Comment: @montonero what is the path of the installation logger?

Comment: It depends on system settings. Usually Windows Installer does not store logs. But it could be enabled either system-wide or for a particular installation. See here for details https://superuser.com/questions/180281/what-folder-are-installation-logs-in